# Chromecast custom receiver send custom metadata

Tags: android, chromecast, custom-receiver

I have chromecast custom receiver. I know how to send the common key values through `mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Something");` and capture them in the receiver. I am wondering if there is a way to send custom fields as metadata. Something like `mediaMetadata.putString("...customField", "Something else");`. Each type of media only allows a fixed set of fields, but I would like to change this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use custom keys in MediaMetaData. You can add your own namespace to send the data or you can piggyback on custom data that some api calls provide.